# Issues with a query on the AS/400 with LIKE clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, ibm-midrange

We are using Hibernate to connect to AS/400. We are having issues with a query on the AS/400 
with the `LIKE` clause.

The following error is shown:

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0131] Operands of LIKE not compatible or not valid

My query is its auto generated by Hibernate:

```
select tab_parame0_.C1IMCD as C1_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NINB as C2_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1JXCD as C3_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HLTX as C4_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HMTX as C5_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1HDST as C6_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NGNB as C7_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NJNB as C8_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1NFNB as C9_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NHNB as C10_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HCST as C11_560_
from RYC1REP tab_parame0_
where lower(tab_parame0_.C1HLTX) like lower(?)
order by tab_parame0_.C1IMCD asc
fetch first 10 rows only
```

Comment: What SQL statement are you using?

Comment: My query is its auto generated by hibernate 

Hibernate: select tab_parame0_.C1IMCD as C1_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NINB as C2_560_, tab_parame0_.C1JXCD as C3_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HLTX as C4_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HMTX as C5_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HDST as C6_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NGNB as C7_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NJNB as C8_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NFNB as C9_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NHNB as C10_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HCST as C11_560_ from RYC1REP tab_parame0_ where lower(tab_parame0_.C1HLTX) like lower(?) order by tab_parame0_.C1IMCD asc fetch first 10 rows only

Comment: Are you sure you a populating the ? in like lower(?)  I would expect for a like statement to see LIKE '%searchfor%'  on an AS/400 query.

Comment: Yes I am using '%searchfor%' with the like clause actually hibrenate displays the above query but the value is the same '%searchfor%'

Answer (score 3):

[SQL0131](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzala/rzalaml.htm#messages__SQL0131) indicates a type mismatch.

What datatype is tab_parame0_.C1HLTX?  What datatype is your query parameter?

**Please include your HQL/JPQL query source code for comparison**.

You may have to set up an SQL trace to see exactly what the AS/400 is receiving.

See [How do I obtain trace information from my Java program using the Toolbox?](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/faq.html#faqM)

---

I recommend you change `LIKE LOWER(:parameter)` to `LIKE :parameter` in your source query and use `.toLowerCase()` when you set the parameter and see how that works.

Comment: Datatype in AS400 is CHAR and I am sending the character data also

Comment: I updated my answer to re-request your HQL query source code and provided a link to enable tracing in the Toolbox jdbc driver.

Comment: I am not using the HQL I am using the open JPA and the query generated by the the JPA is :select tab_parame0_.C1IMCD as C1_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NINB as C2_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1JXCD as C3_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HLTX as C4_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HMTX as C5_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1HDST as C6_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NGNB as C7_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NJNB as C8_560_,
tab_parame0_.C1NFNB as C9_560_, tab_parame0_.C1NHNB as C10_560_, tab_parame0_.C1HCST as C11_560_
from RYC1REP tab_parame0_
where lower(tab_parame0_.C1HLTX) like lower(?)
order by tab_parame0_.C1IMCD asc
fetch first 10 rows only

Comment: It seems 'lower' at the right hand side is creating problem. How to set Filter in DAO so that it puts only 'lower' at the left side of the HQL it generates e.g. where lower(tab_parame0_.C1HLTX) like ?